"Reply-To" header not correctly handled in Gmail on Android
When replying to an email on an Android phone using Gmail, the reply-to header is ignored and the reply goes to the sender instead of the address provided in the Reply-To header. The same email sent to a desktop using Windows 11 works correctly and the reply to is addressed to the correct person.
What can I do as this is a serious bug from Google?

Google Bug Boards perhaps, or the specific community (in this case Gmail's support page) would be my first two picks.
